# Cannot send emails using Sendgrid on Heroku Cedar stack

Tags: heroku, smtp, sendgrid, cedar

I receive the following error: 451 Authentication failed: Maximum credits exceeded.

However when I check the sendgrid dashboard on heroku it says:

[image]

Is the dashboard outdated? It says I still have remaining credits...

Comment: you should open up a support ticket on this one. http://support.sendgrid.com/.  Also, I would double check that you're using the right credentials.

Comment: I talked to customer support from Sendgrid. They told me to get in touch with Heroku. 
I followed this tutorial from Heroku to set up the email service in the first place and it was working until 5 days ago. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#ruby-rails

Comment: And if you type `heroku config`, are `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` assigned the correct values?

Comment: Its best just to use SendGrid directly, without the add on. Alternatively, MailGun has a better integration with Heroku